# Postman multiple api calls using the values from response body

Tags: postman

I am a new postman user. I attached a screenshot to show you my parameters. I get a new "nextpagetoken" every time I call this api. The listid and activitytypeid are not changing. What I want to do is finding a way to rerun this call automatically until there is no "nextpagetoken" in the response body. I also want to save the response of each call, separately if possible.

I've found a few solutions but given that I am a new user, I didn't fully understand them + none of them explains how to save the response automatically.

[image: postman screenshot]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not include a lot of details in your question, so I am going to use a generic example for this answer.

Let's say you want to call `https://mysite/token` with a **Post** call, from which you get a response using json with a token you need to reuse.

1. In your collection, create a new request. Select POST and write the url `https://mysite/token`.
2. Go into the tests tab. Assuming that the output of the call to your url is a json structure like this

```json
{
    "jwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c"
}
```

You will need to write a script to capture the token like this:

```js
var data = pm.response.json();
var accessToken = data.jwt;

pm.globals.set("token", accessToken);
```

3. now you can use it in your next request. Either in the url, if the next page is a get (e.g. `http://mysite/page?token={{token}}`) or anywhere else, like the parameters.

Just enclose it in double curly brackets. `{{token}}`

You will also be able to see it in your globals, or get it in another script using `pm.globals.get("token")`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can create an environment which, if selected, is accessible globally. Then you would call that variable by accessing it `{{likethis}}`

Comment: Thanks, SimonJL! Could you please elaborate on your answer to help me understand how this is going to help me automate the process and save the responses afterward?